# How to install onAPI/tbb on alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, tbb, intel-oneapi

I'm currently running alpine on a docker, and I've tried installing the tbb library of intel's oneAPI via pip and also tried making it from source, and none of the those did work, is there any way to do that? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

As per the oneTBB system requirements, the Alpine operating system is not supported.
Please refer to the below links for more details.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/intel-oneapi-threading-building-blocks-system-requirements.html

You can try installing oneTBB on the supported OS and let us know with the detailed steps you have followed if you face any issues.

Comment: Alright, appreciated.